# Android minifyEnabled true causes app to crash

Tags: android, minify, android-app-bundle

When I generate an app bundle (release) with minifyEnabled true, when I install the app on a device and run it I get this error:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: xxxxxxxxxxxxx PID: 12723
l.b
at i.a.h.a.c.d.i(:39)
at i.a.h.a.c.d.e(Unknown Source:10)
at f.s.d.i(:4)
at l.n.k.a.a.f(Unknown Source:8)
at d.a.i0.run(:2)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

NB: I edited the original question because Facebook was not the cause of the crash.

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct App ID

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to proguard rules that are not configured correctly. Check if it works when you add this to your proguard rules:

```
-keep class com.facebook.** {
   *;
}
```